# ruby executing remote scripts in one line. (like installing rvm)

Tags: ruby, linux, bash, shell

install rvm in one line example:

```
user$ bash < <(curl -s https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/install/rvm)
```

Now, say I have a ruby scripts like this at http://blah.com/helloworld.rb

```
puts "what's ur name?"
name = gets.chomp
puts "hello world from web, #{name}"
```

I would like to achieve this it in my shell without creating a temp file in one line or even better one command.

```
wget http://blah.com/helloworld.rb; ruby helloworld.rb; rm helloworld.rb
```

I have tried this, but user prompt will be ignored because of earlier pipe.

```
curl -s http://blah.com/helloworld.rb | ruby
```

What's the correct way to executing a remote ruby script? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Like this:

```
ruby < <(curl -s http://blah.com/helloworld.rb)
```

Ruby evaluates ruby code similarly to how bash evaluates shell code

Comment: the first `<` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 6):

Another Ruby option based on Calibre install for shell scripts:

```
ruby -e "require 'open-uri'; system open('http:// or local file').read"
```

The same for Ruby scripts:

```
ruby -e "require 'open-uri'; eval open('http:// or local file').read"
```

**Edited**: Fixed missing quote and added Ruby script execution

Comment: You're right I forgot a quote and change it to work with ruby scripts. I'm going to edit it to fix it. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

From http://brew.sh/:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/mxcl/homebrew/go)"
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Ruby code, you have to reopen stdin and tie it to the controlling terminal device `/dev/tty`!

```
rubyscript="$( cat <<-'EOF'
puts "what's ur name?"
name = gets.chomp
puts "hello world from web, #{name}"
EOF
)"

ruby <(echo '$stdin.reopen(File.open("/dev/tty", "r"))'; echo "$rubyscript")
```